# How to make D3 treemap cross-browser compatible in functionality and appearance?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This code at http://bl.ocks.org/PMeinshausen/5806106 was perfect for me to model after, as I viewed it in Chrome anyway... First click opens a second level of hierarchy, second click can take the user to database records...

But what needs to change in the code provided on that page, to make it function as two separate tiers of a hierarchy, and in multiple colors? I want it to be the same in Firefox and IE 11 as it currently appears in my Safari and Chrome.

Color referenced here but this may not be the problem:

```
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();
```

I have no idea how the hierarchy is collapsing in Firefox/IE.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I would like http://bl.ocks.org/PMeinshausen/5806106 in Firefox or IE 11 to be the same as in Chrome or Safari - I would like multiple colors, not gray only, and two levels of hierarchy, not one...

Comment: Well the colours don't work because the `background` attribute is used -- this can be fixed easily: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/2617399c2656b133ca22 The hierarchy works for me in Firefox.

Comment: Many thanks, that solves it.

Comment: Another browser compatibility issue: labels do not appear on boxes in IE 11 for Windows 7. Multiple pages on blockbuilder.org would not load in IE 11; I think it's the site. Also, this version of the diagram does not total the boxes at the top level - tooltip says NaN. But I will work on those things.